# Left Join with Subclass in Parent Repository Symfony

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, left-join, subclass

I'm trying to do leftJoin with subclass in parent(Report) repository than getting '500 internal server error'. I am doing like this as below.
Here ReportCallOut table 'id'(PK) field is foreign key of Report table 'id'(PK).

```
    class ReportRepository extends EntityRepository
            {
                public function getPage($page = 1, $perPage = null, $filter = null) {

                    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')                   
                               ->leftJoin('r.client', 'c')                             
 ->leftJoin('ACMEModulesReportCentreBundle:ReportCallOut', 'rc', 'WITH', 'r.id=rc.id')
                               ->leftJoin('r.site', 's')                       
                               ->leftJoin('r.status', 'st');
            }
```

After adding leftJoin when I print $qb->getQuery()->getSQL(); than getting 500 internal server error.

> **ReportController.php**

```
class ReportCentreController extends ModuleController
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request, $page)
    {

        $request->getSession()->set('signBack', $request->getUri());


        $reportsRepository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('ACMEModulesReportCentreBundle:Report');

        $perPage = $this->container->getParameter('pagination_per_page');

        $filter = $this->get('acme_core.filters')->getFilter();
        $filter['division'] = $this->division;

        if ($this->isGranted('ROLE_REPORT_CENTRE_CAN_VIEW_OWN_REPORTS', $this->module)) {
            $filter['createdBy'] = $this->getUser();
        }


        $reportsPaginator = $reportsRepository->getPage($page, $perPage, $filter);

    }
}
```

> **ReportRepository.php**

```
class ReportRepository extends EntityRepository
        {
            public function getPage($page = 1, $perPage = null, $filter = null) {

                $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')                   
                           ->leftJoin('r.client', 'c')
                           ->leftJoin('r.site', 's')                       
                           ->leftJoin('r.status', 'st');
        }
```

> **Report.php**

```
    abstract class Report {


        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected  $id;

        /**
        * @Gedmo\Versioned
        * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
        */
    }
```

> **ReportCallOut.php**

```
class ReportCallOut extends Report {

       // protected $locked = false;
        /**
        * @Gedmo\Versioned
        * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
        */
        private $date;

        /**
        * @Gedmo\Versioned
        * @ORM\Column(type="time", nullable=true)
        */
        private $time;

        /**
        * @Gedmo\Versioned
        * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
        */
        protected $job;
    }
```

Comment: As you are using Symfony: What does your app.log or dev.log say? You should get the PHP-error there to get on with. You can find it in <app_directory>/var/logs/dev.log or <app_directory>/var/logs/prod.log, depending on your setup.

Comment: I have checked in dev.log file but nothing is there.

Comment: As per my assumption, I am doing something wrong with syntax for left join. I want leftJoin with subclass.

Comment: If the error is within the app, there should be sometething in your app's logs. If there's nothing in your app's logs, there is another log of your webserver (for apache on Linux those logs are found in /var/log/apache2 ). If the server produces an error (means answering with a 500 error) there must be some log that contains information ...

Comment: I am doing that in my localhost.

Comment: Just want to know that how I can do leftJoin with my subclass at the moment while I am printing query before execution than it's showing auto assign in LeftJoin but I can't use that table alias for other field.

Here is some part of query.

Comment: Here is some part of query.
FROM reports r0_ LEFT JOIN LEFT JOIN reports_call_out r1_ ON r0_.id = r1_.id LEFT JOIN reports_service r2_ ON r0_.id = r2_.id 

But I can't use that alias r1_ for reports_call_out to get Job Number. Any Idea @Fuzzzzel ??

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, If not work then share your Entity files of "ReportCallOut" and "client".

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$clientRepository = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:client");
$where = ' c.cId=:id and c.cStatus !=9 ';

if (!empty($searchKey)) {
    $where .= " AND (r.rName LIKE '%" . $searchKey . "%'
                        OR c.cFirstName LIKE '%" . $searchKey . "%'
                        OR c.cLastName LIKE '%" . $searchKey . "%') ";
}

$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->select('r.rId,c.cId')
        ->leftJoin('r.client', 'c')
        ->leftJoin('ACMEModulesReportCentreBundle:ReportCallOut', 'rc', 'WITH', 'r.rId=rc.rcId')
        ->leftJoin('r.site', 's')
        ->leftJoin('r.status', 'st')
        ->where($where)
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->getQuery();
$resultData = $qb->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Comment: I am getting error "Uncaught Exception: Request stack is empty"